# How do I get an image to stretch itself to automatically fit a screen in CSS3?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get a VERTICAL image to stretch, automatically fitting the top and bottom of any screen. How do I do that in CSS3?

Here is what I have, if it would help at all:

```
.logo{
   height: 700px;
   width: 150px;
}
```

It is not a background image either.

Comment: if it isn't a background-image and cannot be made to be then you may be out of luck.

Comment: width 100% or height 100% does that? If I'm understanding your question.

Comment: @Wayne ...provided the parent container has a height. Or you can use javascript to get `window.height` and set the image height to that.

Comment: Are you ok with using javascript/jQuery to accomplish this?

Comment: I should not use any javascript for this, just plain CSS. @NickCarson

Comment: Add `html, body { width: 100%; height: 100%; }` and then `width: 100%; height: 100%;` to the child that you want to be 100%.

Answer (score 1):

```
.logo{
  height: 100vh;
}
```

You might also want to set the width to `auto` to preserve proportions...

([reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#Viewport-percentage_lengths))

Comment: Viewport units don't work in IE8 and earlier, so this answer may not be the best for everyone with this problem.

Comment: True, but it appears that OP specifically asked for a CSS3 solution.

Answer (score 1):

Best way would be to make it a background of div which has height and width set to 100% and then give it a special background setting so it wont be distorted. Maybe this is what you need.

```
/*
This is needed for 100% height of the div as the percentage refers to the parent element.
*/
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

/*
This is the actual image
*/
.image {
    background: #000 url(https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png) repeat-x;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

<body>
    <div class="image"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        body, html {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        img {
            height: 100%;
            width: auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png"/>
</body>
</html>
```